# How to a fix this query? I'm continuing to get an ERROR CODE 1248 in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm continuing to get an ERROR CODE 1248 in mySQL
  SELECT INV_NUM, AVG_INV, (INV_AMOUNT - AVG_INV) AS DIFF
    FROM CH08_INVOICE,
        (SELECT AVG(INV_AMOUNT)  AS AVG_INV  FROM CH08_INVOICE)
    GROUP BY INV_NUM, AVG_INV, INV_AMOUNT- AVG_INV;

Comment: I see potentially more than one problem with this query, but I can tell you that error code 1248 implies that you are missing an alias on a table.  This is most likely coming from the inner `SELECT` but then again there may be other problems.

Comment: Indeed. Every derived table (select within a select) must have its own alias.

Comment: Where do I add the alias on the inner SELECT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql error code 1248](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718444/mysql-error-code-1248)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT INV_NUM, AVG_INV, (INV_AMOUNT - AVG_INV) AS DIFF
FROM CH08_INVOICE,
(SELECT AVG(C2.INV_AMOUNT)  AS AVG_INV  FROM CH08_INVOICE C2) AS T
GROUP BY INV_NUM, AVG_INV, INV_AMOUNT- AVG_INV;
```

I'm not sure you need the group by, since you do not aggregate the invoice amount.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add alias name for your inner query.Something similar to :

```
(SELECT AVG(c.INV_AMOUNT)  AS AVG_INV  FROM CH08_INVOICE c)
```

As both the inner query and outer query are working on the same table